# iOS open Facebook and Twitter app share page

Tags: ios, facebook, twitter, share

I want to open the Facebook and twitter app from my application. At the same time I have a text which has to be auto populated in the Facebook share box. How do I achieve this? I am able to open the app now. But how do I open the share page and pass the text to be populated.

The same with Twitter.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily post to facebook with image and text. For this you don't have to exit your app. Try this:

```
- (void) postFacebook {

    if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {
        SLComposeViewController *fbSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
        [fbSheet setInitialText:@"Your Text here"];
        [fbSheet addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon-144.png"]];
        [fbSheet addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://asdf.com"]];
        [[CCDirector sharedDirector] presentViewController:fbSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else {

        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                  initWithTitle:@"Sorry!!!"
                                  message:@"You can't share on facebook right now, make sure your device has an internet connection and you have at least one facebook account setup in your device."
                                  delegate:self
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
```

}

For tweeter do this:

```
- (void) callTwitter {

    if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter])
    {
        SLComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
        [tweetSheet setInitialText:@"Your text here"];
        [tweetSheet addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon-144.png"]];
        [tweetSheet addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://asdf.com"]];
        [[CCDirector sharedDirector] presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                  initWithTitle:@"Sorry!!!"
                                  message:@"You can't send a tweet right now, make sure your device has an internet connection and you have at least one twitter account setup in your device."
                                  delegate:self
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add the SOCIAL.FRAMEWORK by going to

> BuildPhases -> LinkBinaryWithLibraries

Also in the ViewController don't forget to import at the top `#import <Social/Social.h>`

**EDIT:**

Well I found this in SO:

```
NSString *myMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                       [self.txtAdreca.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"fb://publish/profile/me?text=%@",urlString];
BOOL canOpenURL = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:post]];
if (canOpenURL) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:post]];
}
```

For tweeter:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"twitter://status?id=12345"]];
```

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: Don't forget to add the **Social.framework** by going to BuildPhases -> LinkBinaryWithLibraries. Also in the ViewController don't forget to import at the top **#import <Social/Social.h>**

Comment: @Rashad Thank you for the reply It was usefull But it is that I have to open the app and post it there. Any way to do that?

Comment: @Rashad Thank you Rshad. Can i use this for twitter too?

Comment: You surely can open the page in tweeter app, but I am not sure about if the text parameter will work or not.